# Laravel: showing information from two related models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 in a project and I'm having trouble getting the information from related models to display correctly. The program is for a small veterinary clinic where pet owners are first registered, and then each of their pets (each owner can have many) is added. In turn, each pet can have multiple consults, vaccinations, documents, etc. Because there are a minimum of three layers involved for each, I though it would be best to keep the url/paths as simple as possible, so instead of a pet's url being /owner/1/pet/1, I kept it as /pet/1, which I believe is why nothing I've tried seems to work as it should (all examples I've seen follow the first path).

**Pets Controller**

I can create new pets with no problem, all their information is saved and can be edited as well. The problem is when I try to view each of them, some all look as they should with their respective owner information, but others (the newest) give me an error `Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\veterinary\resources\views\pets\show.blade.php)`

```
public function index()
{
    $pets = Pet::all();
    $owner = Owner::find($pets);  
    return view('pets.index', compact('owner', 'pets'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pet= new Pet;
    //////////////
    $pet->save();
}

public function show(Pet $pet)
{
    $owner = Owner::find($pet);  
    return view('pets.show', compact('owner', 'pet'));
}
```

**Owners Controller**

I can show the owner's information with no problem, but I can't seem to be able to retrieve a list of the pets registered under their name. I've tried doing it different ways and have gotten different results (no errors but no pets found, object is null, query could not be converted to string, etc.). I left the functions with the commented ways I've tried so far.

```
public function index()
{
    $owners = Owner::all();
    return view('owners.index', compact('owners'));
}

public function getPets($id)
{
    $pets = Pet::owner($id)->get();
    return $pets;
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $owner = new Owner;
    //////////////
    $owner->save();
}

public function show(Owner $owner)
{
    //$pets = Owner::pets();  
    //$owner = Owner::find($owner->id_owner);
    //$pets = $this->getPets($owner->owner_id);
    //$pets = Pet::find($owner)->owner()->where('id_owner', '=', $owner->id_owner)->get();

    $pets = DB::table('pets')->where('owner_id','=',$owner->id_owner);
    $pets = Pet::find($pets)->owners;
    return view('owners.show', compact('owner', 'pets'));
}
```

**Pets Model**

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner');
}
```

**Owners Model**

```
public function pets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pet');
}
```

Apologies for the extremely long post, I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to properly achieve all of this. I've tried all sorts of different ways over the last couple of days, ending up with partially working outcomes or straight up messing everything up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: this is not how it works ..

Comment: pet should be associated to an owner as it is saved ..

Comment: or if this is a many many to relationship .. then use belongsToMany

Comment: I don't think it's a many to many relationship, each Owner can have many pets (hasMany), but each pet can only have one owner. In the store function from the pets controller I did try using `$owner->pets()->save($pet);` before but it doesn't go through, it just displays an error and doesn't save the new pet, which is why I went back to using `$pet->save();` instead, but I do think that's part of the reason why the newest pets saved can't be accessed (only the previous ones). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `$owner = Owner::find(1);` then .. `$pet = new Pet;` blahblah , `$pet->owner_id = $owner->id; $pet->save();`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work either. It saves the new pet like normal but it's assigning the owner id from the first (1) owner registered, not the one it belongs to, for it to save the correct one I have to do `$pet->owner_id = $request->input('owner_id');` where I receive the correct id through the url (/pets/create?owner=id). Even if I do this, I'm still getting an error when trying to access the newly saved pet `Trying to get property of non-object (pets\show.blade.php)`.

Comment: lol .. it's just an example .. you can dynamically save it per user using `$owner = Owner::find($request->owner_id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this just follow this steps.

setting up our model relationship ..

**Pets Model**

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner');
}
```

**Owners Model**

```
public function pets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pet');
}
```

now .. our **Owner Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $owners = Owner::with('pets')->get();
    return view('owners.index', compact('owners'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $owner = new Owner;
    // $owner->blahblah = $request->blahblah;
    $owner->save();
}

public function show(Owner $owner)
{
    $owner->pets;
    return view('owners.show', compact('owner'));
}
```

in the **owner.index** you can see all owners using

```
<ul>
@foreach($owners as $owner)
    <li>{{ $owner->somefield }}
        <ul>
        @foreach($owner->pets as $pet)
            <li>{{ $pet->somefield }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

in **owner.show**

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ $owner->somefield }}
        <ul>
        @foreach($owner->pets as $pet)
            <li>{{ $pet->somefield }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> and that is how you access pets using the owner ..

now our Pet Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $pets = Pet::with('owner')->get();
    return view('pets.index', compact('pets'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    // there are several way to save this pet ..
    // 1

    $pet = new Pet;
    $pet->owner_id = $request->owner_id;
    // $pet->somefield = $request->somevalue;
    $pet->save();

    // 2
    $owner = Owner::find($request->owner_id);
    $owner->pet()->create(['somefield'=>$request->somevalue]);

    // 3
    $pet = new Pet;
    $pet->somefield = $request->somevalue;
    $owner = Owner::find($request->owner_id);
    $pet = $owner->pet()->save($pet);
}

public function show(Pet $pet)
{
    $pet->owner;
    return view('pets.show', compact('pet'));
}
```

for the `pet views`, they have the same logic as the `owner views` ..

**pets.index**

```
<ul>
@foreach($pets as $pet)
    <li>{{ $pet->somefield }}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ $pet->owner->somefield }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

**pets.show**

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ $pet->somefield }}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ $pet->owner->somefield }}</li>
            <li>My Owner's other pets
            <ul>
            @foreach($pet->owner->pets()->where('id','!=',$pet->id)->get as $otherpet)
                <li>{{ $otherpet->somefieldlikepetname }}</li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

hope this really helps ..

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed and it worked perfectly, I seriously can't thank you enough. The owners are now displaying all their pets like I needed, and it turns out I had actually gotten pets to work before, I totally forgot I added a new column to the database table and because the new entries were null here it kept giving me the error I mentioned a few times. Let that be my dumb moment of the day. Thanks again!